# Titanium Alloy builds successfully but index.html not found

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, titanium-alloy

I'm exploring Titanium Alloy at the moment.
So created a project based on the Two-tabbed Alloy Application template provided by Appcelerator in the dashboard.
When I run the app with Titanium Mobile Web Previewer as run config, it compiles successfully, but when it opens the browser I get a page with only the text: 'File /index.html not found'. I googled and searched, but I cant find a solution.

By the way, the console reads:

```
Titanium Command-Line Interface, CLI version 3.1.0, Titanium SDK version 3.0.2.GA
Copyright (c) 2012-2013, Appcelerator, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
[INFO] :   Compiling "development" build
```

and then it opens the browser.

Comment: Does it work if you just run the base project before you modify it?